# Is there a way to return the value of an integer in a list

Tags: python

Trying to return an integer of an item from a list of values. For example

after splitting `Hotdog : 3.00` with `.split()`

I get
`['Hotdog', ':', '3.00']`

What can I do to return the `'3.00'`?

thanks

Comment: You can access the third value of the array: `float(array[2])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it

- by knowing it's exact position

  ```
  str_val = "Hotdog : 3.00".split()[2]
  ```
- by knowing it's last item

  ```
  str_val = "Hotdog : 3.00".split()[-1]
  ```

To get it as a number

```
# as float
val = float("Hotdog : 3.00".split()[2])

# as int, you need intermediate float as '3.00' is not direct int
val = int(float("Hotdog : 3.00".split()[2]))
```